# Use Fedora 34 Terminal color palette/fonts in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: gnome, 21.10

I like the color palette and fonts used by Terminal in Fedora 34, how can I replicate those in Ubuntu 21.10, both are using the same Gnome 40

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the terminal? The Gnome terminal has a bunch of themes built in, it seems likely it will be one of them.

Comment: To be ontopic you really need to tell us all you can from the F34 side. Terminal will have a font name in its preferences. And probably also a location for a file that holds the ls colors.

Comment: Look at `env` on both machines.

Comment: Look at what is used in Fedora; and just replicate that config into Ubuntu. It's open source code; but in this case you don't need to look at code, but can replicate everything you choose to via settings.  (*fonts etc will be available to both; you need to work out what fonts you like though for example*)